# Problem in publishing "Header" in each page in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not getting "Header" printed in my CSS table, while it is working well with "Footer."

This is the code for HTML table content. It goes till page 4. However since the word limit post constrain me to write the complete code. so I have removed the boy which mainly contains the rows data.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DEMO TABLE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
a[href]:after {content: none !important;
table {
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
}
thead {display: table-header-group;}
tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}
tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
    .page {
page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<h3>Heading Comes Here</h3> 
<table border="1" style=”width: 100%”>
    <!--<caption>TABLE HEADER</caption>-->
    <div class="page-footer-space">PAGE HEADER</div>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 20%" />
        <col style="width: 40%" />
        <col style="width: 40%" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">AUTOMATION</th>
            <th rowspan="1">MANUAL</th>
            <th rowspan="1">HYBRID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<th>NEW COL ONE</th>-->  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">TABLE FOOTER</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
            <th>FILE 1</th>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FILE 1</th>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FILE 2</th>
            <td>FILE 2 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 2 COL 2</td>
        </tr>       
<!--Like so--> 
        </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add your table code plz. how do you know your table design?

Comment: Add you're relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? I have changed the table header as

```
<thead>
        <tr ><th colspan="3">PAGE HEADER</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">AUTOMATION</th>
            <th rowspan="1">MANUAL</th>
            <th rowspan="1">HYBRID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<th>NEW COL ONE</th>-->  
        </tr>
</thead>
```

You can try this on a jsfiddle

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DEMO TABLE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
a[href]:after {content: none !important;
table {
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
}
thead {display: table-header-group;}
tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}
tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
    .page {
page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<h3>Heading Comes Here</h3> 
<table border="1" style=”width: 100%”>
    <!--<caption>TABLE HEADER</caption>-->
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 20%" />
        <col style="width: 40%" />
        <col style="width: 40%" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr ><th colspan="3">PAGE HEADER</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">AUTOMATION</th>
            <th rowspan="1">MANUAL</th>
            <th rowspan="1">HYBRID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<th>NEW COL ONE</th>-->  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">TABLE FOOTER</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
            <th>FILE 1</th>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FILE 1</th>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 1 COL 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>FILE 2</th>
            <td>FILE 2 COL 1</td>
            <td>FILE 2 COL 2</td>
        </tr>       
<!--Like so--> 
        </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though this is not exactly the page header, but for now I can use it in my case. Thanks @akshay kishore

Comment: Not to be pushy, but if this helped you could you please consider upvoting my answer

Comment: Yes definitely...:)